# Can I define multiple custom exceptions in java in a single class file and invoke them via methods?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, try-catch, throws

I'm trying to get into exception handling via custom exceptions.

I'm creating the class CustomExceptions and extending Exception as follows:

```
public class CustomExceptions extends Exception{
    public CustomExceptions (String s) {
        super(s);
    }
```

However, rather than having to create multiple files for every custom exception I want, or bloating my main class file, I'd like to put all of my custom exceptions in this class and invoke them via a method

So let's say that I want to handle 2 situations: When the user tries to input a seat reservation, but the seat is already taken, and when the user tries to provide a ticket for someone outside of the age range.

Can I create 2 methods inside of the CustomExceptions class which invoke the constructor passing a custom message to it?

```
    public void seatTaken(String s) {
        String s = "The seat is taken, please choose a new one";
        CustomExceptions(s);

    }

    public void notOldEnough(String s) {
      String s = "User is not old enough for this movie.";
      CustomExceptions(s)

    }
}
```

Would this work? Or am I forced to create multiple custom exception files?

Comment: `throw new CustomExceptions(s);` - you should not need more than one "CustomExceptions" class (unless you want to throw another type of `CustomException` for some reason). What "methods" do you want to provide in a custom exception?

Comment: Thank you, your comment made me realize how silly it was to create multiple custom exceptions.

I was under the impression that they had to accomodate for specific situations, but I just realized I can just pass my message as a parameter during the try block.

Comment: why would you want to do that? Reconsider why you use exceptions and why you would want to use custom exceptions. It should become clear that a single custom exception can serve both purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally custom exceptions **should** be defined in the top level. Because, almost universally, these exceptions are **part of the interface** of the package or module.

If the user cannot see them, then how are they going to **catch** them separately? And if you don't want to catch them separately, then why would you need separate classes?

However, if you must, you can include them into a class for which they are required:

```
public class SeatReservationSystem {
    public static class ReservationFailedException {
        ... constructors taking a message ...
    }

    public static class SeatTakenException extends ReservationFailedException {
        ... constructors taking a message ...
    }

    public static class OutsideAgeException extends ReservationFailedException  {
        ... constructors taking a message ...
    }

    ....
}
```

---

After that you can create any method that *returns* them as required. Don't create methods that *throw* them as the compiler won't see those as exit points of the block you're in, and you'll get strange situations.

Here is some code to show what I mean:

```
// wrong
public static void throwRuntimeException() throws RuntimeException {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}

// correct, but dangerous
public static RuntimeException createRuntimeException() {
    return new RuntimeException();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String initializeMeOrThrowException;
    if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
        // compiler doesn't recognize that the method always throws an exception 
        throwRuntimeException();

        // this the compiler can understand, there is an explicit throw here:
        // throw createRuntimeException();

        // but this is the pitfall, it doesn't do anything:
        // createRuntimeException();
    } else {
        initializeMeOrThrowException = "Initialized!";
    }

    // Compiler error for throwRuntimeException and createRuntimeException without throws:
    // "The local variable initializeMeOrThrowException may not have been initialized"
    System.out.println(initializeMeOrThrowException); 
}
```

However, experience learns me that I forget the `throws` statement for the `throw createException(...);` method, and the stupid compiler doesn't warn me about that (even though the statement is utterly useless without it). So I try and not use either.

---

Note that I'm not certain if you should use exceptions for this. If your system is a reservation system, then refusing tickets is not *that exceptional*. Returning a `ReservationResult` makes more sense.